# $order get transaction id empty woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hi I'm currently developing a plugin for woo-commerce payment gateway

I need help to access transaction id on process payment function

based on documentation to get transaction id by using this code

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
  global $woocommerce;
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );     
  $transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id()

//do stuff
}
```

but the result of $transaction_id is empty. but when i tried to access something like $order->get_total() and get_payment_method() is work.

I have tried to obtain it from metadata but also return empty on the transaction id.

`$transaction_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_transaction_id', true);`

any idea how to get the transaction id ?

Order object :

````
{“id”:76,
”parent_id”:0,
”status”:”processing”,
”currency”:”EUR”,
”version”:”4.0.1″,
”prices_include_tax”:false,
”date_created”:{“date”:”2020-04-23 12:17:27.000000″,”timezone_type”:3,
”timezone”:”Europe/Berlin”},
”date_modified”:{“date”:”2020-04-23 12:17:27.000000″,”timezone_type”:3,
”timezone”:”Europe/Berlin”},
”discount_total”:”0″,
”discount_tax”:”0″,
”shipping_total”:”3.99″,
”shipping_tax”:”0″,
”cart_tax”:”0″,
”total”:”22.99″,
”total_tax”:”0″,”customer_id”:2,
”order_key”:”wc_order_0SBeR4y6o7CqX”,
”billing”:{“first_name”:”Mustain123″ ”last_name”:”Billah”,
”company”:””,
”address_1″:”Alfred-Messel-Weg 8″,
”address_2″:””,
”city”:”Darmstadt”,
”state”:””,”postcode”:”64287″,”country”:”DE”,
”email”:”mustain.bilah.4@gmail.com”,
”phone”:”+4915774087126″},”
shipping”:{“first_name”:”Mustain 123″,
”last_name”:”Billah”,
”company”:””,
”address_1″:”Alfred-Messel-Weg 8″,
”address_2″:””,
”city”:”Darmstadt”,
”state”:””,
”postcode”:”64287″,”country”:”DE”},
”payment_method”:”cryptopay”,”
payment_method_title”:”CryptoPay”,
”transaction_id”:””,
”customer_ip_address”:”::1″,”customer_user_agent”:”Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0″,”created_via”:”checkout”,”customer_note”:””,”date_completed”:null,”date_paid”:{“date”:”2020-04-23 12:17:27.000000″,”timezone_type”:3,”timezone”:”Europe/Berlin”},”cart_hash”:”49f0749ac4376e4be250c1b86e4b75d0″,”number”:”76″,”meta_data”:[{“id”:2512,”key”:”is_vat_exempt”,”value”:”no”}],”line_items”:{“287″:{}},”tax_lines”:[],”shipping_lines”:{“288″:{}},”fee_lines”:[],”coupon_lines”:[]}```
````